# Javascript if statement cancels while loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, do-while, cancellation

I am currently working on some code, in which i tried to programm a very weak KI. I have done this with an endless while loop with prompts and if statements.
But after the first if statement i couldn't add anymore ifs without, that the loop wouldn't work anymore. I tried many thing but nothing seems to work. I hope you can help me...

```js
var b = 1;
var antwort;
do {
  input = prompt(antwort);

  var eingabe = input.toLowerCase();

  var x = Math.round(Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1;

  if (eingabe === "hallo" || eingabe === "hi") {
    switch (x) {

      case 1:
        {
          antwort = "Hallo!";
          break;
        }

      case 2:
        {
          antwort = "Na, wie geht es dir?";
          break;
        }

      case 3:
        {
          antwort = "Guten Tag!";
          break;
        }

      case 4:
        {
          antwort = "Hi.";
          break;
        }

      case 5:
        {
          antwort = eingabe + ".";
          break;
        }
    }
  } else if (eingabe.includes("gut") === True) {
    antwort = "Das ist schön"
  } else {
    antwort = "Das habe ich nicht verstanden."
  }
} while (1 === 1);
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: "wouldn't work anymore"?

Comment: i am not clear what your are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write boolean literals in all lowercase:

`(eingabe.includes("gut")===True)` should be `(eingabe.includes("gut")===true)`

**EDIT**

I you prefer (I know I do), you can actually omit the `=== true` part. `.includes` returns a boolean anyways:

```
if (eingabe.includes("gut")) {
  //...
}
```

Does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In this `if`:

```
if( eingabe.includes("gut") === True ) {
    // ...
```

`True` will be seen as a variable name. Because javascript keywords are all lowercased, and javascript is a **case sensetive** language. That means that if a keyword contain an uppercase letter, then it's no longer a keyword but a variable name. So this will work fine:

```js
var whiLe = 5;

console.log(whiLe); // work fine
```

but this will not:

```js
var while = 5;

console.log(while); // error
```

Here is a link of all the [**reserved keywords**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) in javascript.

**Note:** that `inludes` is already returning a boolean so there is no need to compare it with `true`, just this will suffice:

```
if( eingabe.includes("gut") ) {
    // ...
```